# Perl: Error handling threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

```
sub worker {
    exit 1;
}

my $thr = threads->create(\&worker);    
while ($thr->is_running()) {
    print "running\n";
}
my $rc = $thr->join();
exit $rc;
```

I come from Python. Is there something similar to try/except that I can use around `while($thr->is_running)`

I get (because I exit 1 in worker):

```
Perl exited with active threads:
0 running and unjoined
1 finished and unjoined       
0 running and detached
```

I want to be able to catch the exit or other compiliation error worker might have

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub worker {
    my $bad = 1/0;
}

my $thr = threads->create( \&worker );
while ( $thr->is_running() ) {
    sleep 1;
}
my $rc = $thr->join();  #NB - RC will be 'undef' because there's no return.
```

OUTPUT:

```
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Illegal division by zero at mythread.pl line 6.
```

Is it possible to catch it the error? and how and where?

Comment: Why does your thread need to exit? You should be exiting the thread using `return`.

Comment: @AKHolland its an example so i can show the error. if i put $a= 0 (without my or something it will do the same). the point is i want to catch whatever error that i might see inside the thread

Comment: Compilation errors are completely different. The script won't run at all if it can't compile in its entirety. Also you've picked a bad example with `$a = 0`, it's one of the only variables that will work fine without `my`.

Comment: @AKHolland whatever the case is. not the point of the question. I want to be able to handle any error that might occur inside the worker thread

Comment: It won't run the thread (or anything else) if you have a compilation error. So yes, it is the point. Any normal error (`die "bleeeh"`) would not require special handling.

Comment: "any" error. not just compilation error. for example, runtime error like invalid value for shared scalar error. is it possible to catch thread from terminating abnormally like from illegal division by zero or something.

Comment: Yes. Return something 'normally' and capture the return code. If it's 'normal' then it worked ;). You can also probably do a try/catch or eval block within your thread to trap fatals as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't call exit in your thread. That exits your whole program. `threads -> exit` is what you want.

http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#EXITING-A-THREAD

> threads->exit()
>
> If needed, a thread can be exited at any time by calling threads->exit() . This will cause the thread to return undef in a scalar context, or the empty list in a list context.
>   When called from the main thread, this behaves the same as exit(0).

- `join` waits for the thread to complete.
- Don't use `$a`. It's a bad variable name anyway, but it's also used for perl sort.
- You're capturing `$rc` but that implies a `return` in your thread. As it, it'll be undefined.

But this will work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub worker {
    sleep 10;
    threads->exit;
}

my $thr = threads->create( \&worker );
while ( $thr->is_running() ) {
    print $thr ->tid, " running\n";
    sleep 1;
}
print $thr ->tid, " not running\n";
sleep 5;
my $rc = $thr->join();  #NB - RC will be 'undef' because there's no return.
```

In the latter case, `$rc` is `undef` because you `exit`ed. You can test for it being undefined if you want to trap an abnormal exit. (Just make sure you do actually return something on a success).

Alternatively, wrap your code in the thread with an `eval` because that won't be a fatal error. Doesn't come up too often, but I'd suggest rather than trying to capture the broad spectrum of possible fatal errors, you're far better off just testing whether it completed successfully instead.

To answer your second question - something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub worker {
    sleep 5;
    my $fatal = 1 / 0;
    return 1;
}

sub otherworker {
    sleep 4;
    eval { my $fatal = 1 / 0; };
    if   ($@) { return $@ }
    else      { return "No error" }
}

my $thr  = threads->create( \&worker );
my $thr2 = threads->create( \&otherworker );

while ( $thr->is_running() ) {
    print $thr ->tid, " running\n";
    sleep 1;
}
print $thr ->tid, " not running\n";

foreach my $thread ( threads->list ) {
    my $return_code = $thread->join;
    if ( not defined $return_code ) {
        print $thread ->tid(), ": terminated abnormally\n";
    }
    else {
        print $thread ->tid, ": exited with $return_code \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i did your test and i have a question. it's part of the orig questions i just posted

Comment: Amended answer with an illustratoin.

Comment: "Don't call exit in your thread. That exits your whole program. threads -> exit is what you want." To be complete, one should note that you can `use threads 'exit' => 'threads_only'` and it will instruct threads that any `exit` is to be taken as ending the thread only and not the entire program. See the [perl doc for more information](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads#use-threads-'exit'-=%3E-'threads_only')